# sfdx doesn't track changes to static resources

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, skuid

We are testing `skuid` (a managed package) with salesforceDX. And using the skid's `"Build base pack"`  followed by the `sfdx force:source:pull`, the `staticresources` folder is created with the files. Now the problem is, if you modify the same pages and regenerate the `staticresources` in the scratch org, `sfdx force:source:pull/status`, doesn't see the changes?

Is this by design, if yes, this is not helping iterative development? Does `sfdx` track changes to the `staticresources`

UPDATE:
If i change the name of the page, while re-creating the `staticresources` (post modification). `sfdx` sees the changes/the new `json` file. But this leave us with 2 files. One before the modification and the new one created post the modification.

Comment: I feel like it should. If not, maybe it's a bug? I'll ask around.

Answer (score 2):

This is bug. The workaround mentioned above is not tenable.

A bug has been filed W-4541603.

Comment: Yes, i missed to mention that its not a workaround